# Getting asked for two-step verification code, but I'm not getting notification on my phone or email

Tags: discussion, login

I have an account, however, when I go to login, it asks for the two-step verification code and I don't think I ever set that up. If I did, I'm not getting it on my phone or on my email account.

Comment: Google Authenticator code perhaps?

Comment: When you login, do you use Google, Facebook, or another account to login?

Comment: Probably should clarify whether this is for Stack Exchange or for your Ubuntu system.

Comment: Is this for your StackExchange account/login or for your computer?  (Read my answer it covers all cases)

Answer (score 1):

If this is for your login to this site, and you use a third-party provider like Google, Facebook, etc. to authenticate, then the two-step verification code handling originates on that side of the system, and you must address the issue with that provider.  More than likely, those systems want you to use your 2FA program like Google Authenticator or similar to generate your 2FA code, and have a fall-back to SMS or Email authentication.  Unfortunately, Ask Ubuntu nor StackExchange have any insight into these third party authentication integrations, and you will have to talk to those providers for support directly.

---

If you are using a StackExchange login directly for the site, I don't *think* it has 2FA as an option (please feel free to correct me if I'm wrong, as I haven't checked as I use Google to authenticate), but that'd require you to contact the staff of StackExchange for assistance (see the "Contact" button at the bottom of every page).

---

If this is for your Ubuntu system, then clarify that and post this as an actual question to Ask Ubuntu.  This will then depend 100% on how your 2FA system is configured with Ubuntu, but the vast majority don't have email / SMS integration.

---

In none of these cases can Meta here on Ask Ubuntu assist you.